# SQL exception due to foreign key constraint trying to create tables

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, constraints, hsqldb, sqlexception

I was trying to create a set of tables using the following script:

```
DROP TABLE ORDERS IF EXISTS;
DROP TABLE INVOICE IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE ORDERS(
    ORDER_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ...
    INVOICE_ID BIGINT,
    ...
    );

CREATE TABLE INVOICE(
    INVOICE_ID BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    ...
    ORDER_ID BIGINT,
    ...
    FOREIGN KEY(ORDER_ID) REFERENCES ORDERS(ORDER_ID)
);
ALTER TABLE ORDERS ADD FOREIGN KEY(INVOICE_ID) REFERENCES INVOICE(INVOICE_ID);
```

This causes sql exception

> java.sql.SQLException: is referenced by FOREIGN KEY constraint:
>   PUBLIC.INVOICE.SYS_FK_10079 in statement [ DROP TABLE ORDERS IF
>   EXISTS]

I couldn't figure out how to solve this ..I need invoiceId in ORDERS table and OrderID in INVOICE table as foreign keys..That is why I used the ALTER TABLE statement..Still ,it seems wrong..
(btw I am using hsqldb)

I would like to know how to do this properly..Any help most welcome..

Comment: I would recommend putting your constrints within the Create Table statement for better readability.

Comment: putting FOREIGN KEY(INVOICE_ID) REFERENCES INVOICE(INVOICE_ID) inside CREATE_TABLE ORDERS causes INVOICE_ID not found error message

Comment: With some test tables this runs perfectly fine for me with your information... Are you sure there are not any contraints on the FK or PK that could let them be set to NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Drop the foreign key on orders first:

```
ALTER TABLE ORDERS DROP FOREIGN KEY(INVOICE_ID) REFERENCES INVOICE(INVOICE_ID);
```

Then run your commands.

Comment: I tried it [sql] Failed to execute:   ALTER TABLE ORDERS DROP FOREIGN KEY(INVOICE_ID) REFERENCES INVOICE(INVOICE_ID)

BUILD FAILED
java.sql.SQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: FOREIGN